# Twitter REST API 1.1 authentication issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been trying to get Twitter followers using REST api 1.1 every time I got **bad authentication error**. I have read almost all documents from Twitters developer blogs and documentation but not getting how to send authorized request to Twitter REST API. I am using parse for twitter log in if someone has any sample code for Twitter auth please share with us.

any help will be highly appreciated.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers.json"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:[@"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=***************,oauth_nonce=*****************, oauth_signature=******************,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=1371709719,oauth_token=*****************, oauth_version=1.0" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]forKey:@"Authorization"];

TWRequest *twRequest = [[TWRequest alloc]initWithURL:url parameters:dict requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

[twRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Response error: %@", error);
    NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Response dictionary: %@", responseDictionary);
}];
```

Comment: post your code which you have tried

Comment: PLease check the updated Question with source code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library.

Here is a sample call so that you can see what it looks like:

```
[twitter getHomeTimelineSinceID:nil count:@"20" successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
    // ...
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```